# Unity 2018 C# - Fbx Running animation scaling with Input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have figured out how to get fbx animations working in Unity for my character in my adventure game, but now I wish to have my character's running animation move with its speed of motion being in relation to the input of the control stick on an xbox controller.

In addition, when I add a walking animation in the future I wish to make a threshold for the control stick input so that the character walks when there is minimal input from the control stick and running when there is more input from the control stick. Any advice?

Here is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    static Animator anim;

    public bool walking;

    public GameObject playerModel, Hero;


    //Transforms
    public Transform playerCam, character, centerPoint;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    //character controller declaration
    CharacterController player;

    //Mouse Rotation
    private float rotX, rotY;

    //Mouse Y Position
    public float mouseYPosition = 1f;

    //Mouse Sensitivity
    public float Sensitivity = 10f;

    //Mouse Zoom
    private float zoom;
    public float zoomSpeed = 2;

    //Clamping Zoom
    public float zoomMin = -2f;
    public float zoomMax = -10f;

    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

    //Move Front Back left & Right
    private float moveFB, moveLR;

    //Movement Speed
    public float Speed = 2f;

    //Velocity of Gravity
    public float verticalVelocity;

    //Jump Distance
    public float jumpDist = 5f;

    //Multiple Jumps
    int jumpTimes;

    //To use with Dialogue Manager
    public DialogueManager DiagM;

    public AudioClip jumpSound;
    public AudioClip HurtSound;

    AudioSource audioSource;

    //knockback

    public float knockBackForce;
    public float knockBackTime;
    private float knockBackCounter;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()



    {
        //character controller
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();


        //mouse zoom
        zoom = -3;

        centerPoint.transform.position = playerCam.transform.position;
        centerPoint.transform.parent = null;

        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update ()

    {

        //if (DiagM.StartDialogue)
        //{ return; }

        //Mouse Zoom Input
        zoom += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomSpeed;
        if (zoom > zoomMin)
            zoom = zoomMin;
        if (zoom < zoomMax)
            zoom = zoomMax;

        //Mouse Camera Input
        playerCam.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, zoom);

        //Mouse Rotation

        rotX += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * Sensitivity;
        rotY -= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity;      

        //Clamp Camera

        rotY = Mathf.Clamp (rotY, -60f, 60f);
        playerCam.LookAt (centerPoint);
        centerPoint.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotY, rotX, 0);




        //Movement Speed
        if (knockBackCounter <= 0)
     {   
        moveDirection = (transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) + (transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        moveDirection = moveDirection * Speed;
        moveDirection.y = verticalVelocity;

        player.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);



        //Movement Rotation

        centerPoint.position = new Vector3 (character.position.x, character.position.y + mouseYPosition, character.position.z);


            //knockback disable


            //Movement Input
            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)

            {

                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, centerPoint.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
                Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(moveDirection.x, 0f, moveDirection.z));
                playerModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(playerModel.transform.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

                if (player.isGrounded == true)

                {
                    anim.Play("Running");                 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (player.isGrounded == true)
                { anim.Play("Idle"); }
            }

            if (player.isGrounded == true)

            {
                jumpTimes = 0;
                verticalVelocity = -Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;       
            }

            else

            {
                verticalVelocity += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Submit"))
            {
                anim.Play("Hello");
            }

            if (jumpTimes < 1)

            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                {
                    verticalVelocity += jumpDist;
                    anim.Play("Jump");
                    audioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpSound, 1F);
                    jumpTimes += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            knockBackCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }

    public void Knockback(Vector3 direction)
    {

        knockBackCounter = knockBackTime;
        anim.SetTrigger("isJumping");
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(HurtSound, 50F);
        moveDirection = direction * knockBackForce;
        moveDirection.y = knockBackForce;
    }


}
```